# How do write only PrivateKey to KeyStore without SSL Certificate with Java?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, store, private

I have a method with it, I can store a private key and certificate in a key store. But I have to store the only private key to the key store without a certificate. Can I change my method in order to write only a private key without a certificate to the key store?

```
public static void writeOnlyPrKeyToKeyStoreFile(PrivateKey privateKey, String keyStoreFileName, String password, String alias,Certificate... certificates) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            final KeyStore ks = readKeyStore(keyStoreFileName, password);
            ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, password.toCharArray(), certificates);
            System.out.println("keyStoreFileName fuer pushKey2Cert: " + keyStoreFileName);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(keyStoreFileName));
            ks.store(fos, password.toCharArray());
            fos.flush();
        } catch (final Exception e) {// only warn!!!throw new RuntimeException(KEYSTORE_Error + "while pushKey2Cert into " + keyStoreFileName + " / Alias " + alias + " / Passwort ", e);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(KEYSTORE_Error + "while pushKey2Cert into  " +  keyStoreFileName + " / Alias " + alias + " / Passwort *****", e);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry`? According to the KeyStore documentation this class is designed to save PrivateKey entries in a KeyStore and the use [setEntry(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setEntry-java.lang.String-java.security.KeyStore.Entry-java.security.KeyStore.ProtectionParameter-).

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The private key needs to have a certificate on it. It can probably only work with a secure key but not with a private key.

Comment: If a cert is required why not just provide a dummy certificate? I don't think KeyStore will validate the key included in the certificate if it matches. May be you can even provide an unsigned certificate. If you retrieve the entry later than you can ignore the cert.